# What is the difference between vmc and cf-cli?

Tags: cloud-foundry

I'm new for cloudfoundry,I search many papers,someone describe vmc,but the otherone describe cf-cli, I wonder that does this two have any difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're basically the same thing; both are command-line clients for interacting with a Cloud Foundry installation. The `vmc` program, written in Ruby, was replaced with the `cf` one about five years ago, and that one is written in Go.

If you're looking for more recent papers, any mention of `vmc` is a good indicator of age.

Comment: `vmc` refers to the original VMware branded version of Cloud Foundry (pre 2013). There was briefly a Ruby version of `cf` (i.e. v5) that succeeded `vmc` and in 2014 the current `cf` (i.e. v6), a Golang version was released.